# If excel matches 3 values then return 4th

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, formula, vlookup

This is my first time posting on any website, so please be gentle lol!

I am trying to figure out what forumula i need to help with the attached tabs;

### Main Sheet

[image: Main Sheet]

### Data Dump

[image: Data Dump CSV]

Goal: to identify how many blocks are due for each block length, at each selected time for each service type. The current UI we have is really poor. this is more user friendly.

My solution?

in each cell there will be a formula to search each time slot for each service type and return the accepted amount for standard/large vehicles from the data dump CSV.

I'm self taught on excel and know some basic macros and formulas however i have admitted defeat here.

I hope this makes sense. I only need the formula to pick up one service type i can amend to suit where necessary.

Thanks in advance for those who take the time to assist.

Edit - [Outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3QmeN.jpg)
[datadump2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NHed0.jpg)

James

Comment: Does this make sense? Thanks for looking into this

Comment: Basically, for each block length (3,3.5,4,4.5 & 5) we have a time slot every 15 minutes. However this only based on what we require at station.  When we download the CSV, i want this file to auto populate each slot based on its hourly length on the main sheet tab. so for each time slot, a formula that is something like - IF (AmFlex Vehicle or AmFlex Vehicle Large) and (Timeslot & Length matches) then return accepted value.

Comment: I have no clue what you mean. Can you add another image where you highlight the parts you talk about?

Comment: hi andreas, I've added 2 new images, one showing  the final outcome from the given data dump and the other showing the 3 criterias in red, and the hourly slots colour coded to match their desination on the outcome file... so there are 2 service types i wish to seperate on the mainsheet, the large and standard. i don't want it to pull the nursery routes or standard routes etc. the accepted value is the value i wish to return into the allocated time slots given that the 3 criterias meet. does that make sense?

Comment: If you have an email address i can email over the file

Comment: Time slot matches on start time? Can you amend the sheets? This would be much easier if you created  key columns in the top (1 before each block length and the total. Or 5 if total simply sums other columns)  and 1 in the bottom images. And used that to lookup/match values. The key would be a concatenation of the 3 values to match on.

Comment: fixed it myself. =sumif was the answer.